# How can I locate a particular Jupyter Notebook using part of its name with JupyterLab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I happen to have many Jupyter Notebooks and some time I want to locate a particular one and open it using part of its name (e.g. the month-year which I always add to the name of a JN). Is it possible to do it with Jupyter Lab?

Here is a snapshot of my JupyterLab screen:

[image]